# Do all the enemies rise again in the blood moon?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

When there is a blood moon in *The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild* fallen enemies are resurrected. Are there any that don't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All enemies return after a blood moon except for:

- Enemies inside Divine Beasts. This includes the unnamed Divine Beast in the Final Trial as part of the EX Champions' Ballad DLC.
- Sentries. These are the enemies on Death Mountain that appear in the quest to get inside Divine Beast Vah Rudiana.
- Master Kohga.

Lynels and Mini-bosses respawn. Mini-bosses include the Hinoxes, Taluses, Moldugas, and the EX Champions' Ballad DLC mini-bosses (Igneo Talus Titan and Molduking).

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  All enemies in the game that you've defeated come back.  Bosses are the likely exception (I haven't checked yet).

This is a change to the Zelda franchise as previously enemies would respawn in you switched areas.  Now, the **only** time they respawn is the Blood Moon.

Comment: In other words, this is present so that respawning enemies have an actual story explanation.

Comment: Can we get an update if overworld bosses are included?

Comment: @Fredy31 I know enemies like the Stone Talus guys are included, if you consider those overworld bosses.

Comment: @Fredy31 Overworld bosses (I'm assuming you're talking about Hinox, Lynel, Guardians, etc.) do respawn during the blood moon.  The only enemies I've not seen respawn are the enemies inside the Divine Beasts after you free them.  Source: personal experience.

Comment: @Cody you cannot return to a Divine Beast after freeing it, so the point is moot.

Comment: @OrangeDog it is not moot. If you go into a Divine Beast, kill half of the enemies, leave the Divine Beast, trigger a blood moon, and then go back in, those half won't respawn.

Comment: @Cody but you said "after you free them"

Comment: Still a true statement.