# Is there a way to make a Blood Moon happen more often?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Is there a way that I can make a blood moon happen more often? Because usually a blood moon happens every 1-2 hours. Is there a way to increase the blood moon occurence?

Comment: Do you mean "can I make blood moons happen more often"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that [the blood moon is based on how often you kill monsters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303261/how-long-does-it-take-the-blood-moon-to-show-up-and-what-does-exactly-respawn-af) (+ some random aspects), the solution to make it spawn more frequently is to kill more monsters.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @Pyritie I tested it quite a bit, no official data thoguh. If you spend all the time killing monsters a blood moon will rise within 15-30 minutes. There are some places in the game where blood moon does not appear, sanctuaries, castle, woodland and maybe others.

Comment: @Pyritie did you see the question I linked? But also, I can back this up personally: I waited for approximately 2 hours real time, sitting in the same spot, waiting for a blood moon. Eventually gave up, went around, whacked some monsters, and before I knew it... blood moon.

Comment: @Grirg additionally, it won't appear if you're doing some actions like climbing or gliding. I once had a fun game of chicken with the blood moon where I saw it coming, so I started gliding. Then I started swimming, then climbing, then gliding again. Of course, it beat me eventually, but it was fun to try to outrun it.

Comment: @Seiyria How do you "outrun" it? Does the clock just stop while you're doing those actions or what?

Comment: @Pyritie pretty much. I'm fairly certain nintendo didn't want a blood moon to happen while the stamina wheel was out in a potentially fatal situation, due to the frustration it could bring.

Comment: I can back this up with my experiences as well.  I spent the first part of my game time collecting towers and shrines and locations, which meant I was running away from every enemy I ran across. I rarely encountered blood moons.  Now I'm into upgrading my armors, which means collecting monster parts by killing monsters, and I get blood moons so often they've become an annoyance.

Answer (score 5):

There's an [in-depth write-up here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/9t0xdz/clarifying_the_time_system_blood_moons_and_lord/) of how blood moons are scheduled. There are two main things you can do to make them arrive quicker.

1. Stay in the overworld. If you're in a shrine, Divine Beast, Hyrule Castle, lost woods, or other situations where you cannot fast-travel, then a blood moon will not be triggered. Doing this you should get one every seven in-game days (2h48m non-cutscene play time).
2. Try to induce heavy resource usage. One user reports triggering panic blood moons after cuccoo attacks. Other ways to fill up the engine's memory may include dropping many items and setting up big explosion chain-reactions.