# Does closing the game reset Blood Moons timer?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

According to [Zelda dungeon](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Blood_Moon), Blood Moon regularly occurs every 2 hours and 48 minutes of gameplay (every unskipped 7 days in-game).

Another [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/340719/87579) confirms that it's a time-based event.

So I'm wondering, do these timers reset when the game is closed? Can I trigger a Blood Moon if I play at most 2 hours straight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This timer counts in-game time and doesn't reset until a blood moon happens. Time spent loading screens and pause menus also doesn't count towards this. The idea is that the Blood Moon happens about once every in-game week.